# Trigger Eclipse's code formatter programmatically from a new file wizard

Tags: eclipse-plugin, formatting, xtext

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin with a wizard (`org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard`) which creates a new file with a basic code template. To simplify the "piecing together" of the file contents, I plan to stuff everything into one long string, inject it into the file, and then call my custom Formatter (inherits `org.eclipse.xtext.formatting.impl.AbstractDeclarativeFormatter`) to clean up all the indentation and so on.

Question is, how do I go about calling the formatter programmatically?
In the wizard I call `IDE.openEditor()` and get back a handle to an `IEditorPart`. What can I do from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I have found my answer:

```java
IEditorPart editor = IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
XtextEditor xed = (XtextEditor)editor;
((SourceViewer)xed.getInternalSourceViewer()).doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);
```

Maybe that will help someone else looking for something similar!

Comment: Where do you have these lines?