# How can I call the Eclipse/Xtext code formatter from a function?

Tags: eclipse, function, xtext, formatter

I would like to be able to call my XText code formatter from a function. I will be calling this as part of my code generator, and possibly from elsewhere. I believe this solution will be generic for any language in Eclipse, not just those implemented with XText.

I have searched for a solution on SO, but have been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions/a point in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks, Sean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923969/trigger-eclipses-code-formatter-programmatically-from-a-new-file-wizard

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, and thanks for the great xtext blog posts Christian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Christian for this link...

[Trigger Eclipse's code formatter programmatically from a new file wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923969/trigger-eclipses-code-formatter-programmatically-from-a-new-file-wizard)

If anybody needs help with a similar issue, let me know. It was straightforward in the end.